# Opencv 3.1.0 with extra modules throws DLL load failed error

Tags: windows, python-2.7, opencv, visual-studio-2015, cmake

Windows 10 32 bit
Opencv 3.1.0
Opencv_contrib
Visual Studio 2015
Python 2.7
CMake

I have been trying to install OpenCV 3.1.0 with extra modules from the opencv_contrib github page. Following many tutorials I use the CMake GUI and configure (to visual studio 14 2015) and generate the opencv/build files. I then load up the gnerated opencv.sln file in Visual Studio and build the BUILD_ALL file and then build the INSTALL file. A successful cv2.pyd file is loaded into python for me under Python27/Lib/site-packages which is the same location for the vanilla opencv 2 and 3 builds you can download. My issue is when I try to import cv2 I get the following error:

> > > import cv2
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I have scoured the internet trying to figure out how to fix the issue. I have downloaded software that repairs DLL paths but didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated I have working on solving this problem for over 30 hours now and am going crazy.

This is a photo from my Dependency Checker

[image]

Comment: You could use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check what dlls the pyd needs (and perhaps cannot find).

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Unfortunately I have no idea what Dependency Walker works (have watched a few vids) and when I tried loading the cv2.pyd file in it threw a bunch of errors which I don't understand.

Comment: You will usually get a bunch of irrelevant errors. Collapse the dependency tree in the top-left part of the window, so that you only have a single level showing (so Ctrl+W, and then click on the + of the root node). Take a screenshot of that window, and attach that to your question.

Comment: Image is at bottom of main question

Comment: See how there's a long list of dlls with names beginning with "opencv_", that have the question mark icon next to them? Those are ones to be concerned about, you can ignore the "API-*". This means that `cv2.pyd` requires those DLLs, but is unable to find them. Either add the directory containing all of those DLLs to your `PATH`, or copy them to where `cv2.pyd` is located. The first is probably a better approach. In second case, there may be dependencies of those opencv DLLs to deal with as well.

Comment: Hey man thanks for all your help. I have found the .dll files in opencv-master/build/install/x86/vc14/bin. When I built the cmake file in visual studio all the tutorials told me to also build the INSTALL targeet created by cmake which is the folder im in(i think). I don't understand how to link these pathways as my cv2.pyd file is sitting  a Python27/Lib/site-packages which is where you have to put it for it to be able to be imported into python.

Comment: So I did that most basic thing I could think of and copied all the .dll files to the same file where cv2.pyd is located and it seems to work. I was wondering if you knew of a way to generate the cv2.pyd with the paths linked so I would have to just brute force copy paste just so it's cleaner. Again thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: By using the Dependency Checker on the cv2.pyd file I was able to determine that I was missing the connections for some modules and features. They were missing their corresponding .dll file. Going into where I built OpenCV with extra modules I found the necessary .dll files and copy pasted them to the same location where the cv2.py is stored in python.